# Orthogonally packing consecutive integer cubes 1x1x1 -nxnxn inside the smallest integer cube.

Tags: 3d, packing-problem

For small n, the problem of orthogonally packing consecutively sized integer cubes 1x1x1 - nxnxn inside the smallest integer cube CxCxC is trivial.  By inspection, the sizes of two largest cubes n and n-1 must bound C, so C = 2n - 1 for small n.  Also by inspection, you can see that by putting the largest cubes in the 8 corners of C, the 9th largest cube must be placed next to 2 other cubes, best case the 7th and 8th largest cubes, so C is bounded by (n-6) + (n-7) + (n-8) = 3n - 21.  This becomes the limitation, in other words, 2n-1 = 3n-21 for n=20, and 2n - 1 < 3n - 21, for n > 20.  n=20 can be said to be a transition point between two bounding equations for C.
Again, this becomes a fairly trivial exercise until n=69 (see http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/CubePacking/ ) with a packing density 90%+.

Q1:  Is packing cubes 1-70 still bounded by 3n - 21 ?  In other words, can cubes 1-70 orthogonally pack into 189x189x189?  Orthogonally means the x,y and z axes of all the cubes point in the same direction, no rotation or tilting allowed.

Q2:  Presumably, for n=70 or a value not much larger, C = 4n - k.  Is this true, or is there some other bounding equation?  If so, what is k, and can you make an argument similar for 3n-21 why k has the value it does?  In other words, can you show that at minimum 4 squares n-a1, n-a2, n-a3, n-a4 must be next to each other, defining a new lower limit for C ?

Q3:  What is the smallest n and C to give a packing density >99%?  I can create this for somewhat large n and an inefficient packing strategy.  I am looking for a better packing strategy and smaller n.

Q4:  Presumably, as n approaches infinity, packing density approaches 100%.  Can you make an argument for this?  My most naïve shelf packing approach did not converge to 100%.  Can your approach?

Q5:  Packing density after transitioning from C=2n-1 to C=3n-21, at n=21, is approx. 72%.  Counterintuitively, packing density goes down as n goes from 21 - 29, and does not return to > 75% until n>=45.  Will similar behavior be seen after the next transition to C=4n-k?

Q6:  Can further transition points be demonstrated for C=5n-k2, C=6n-k3, etc.?

Comment: Aaaand your own ideas and attempts are...? It seems as though you've simply copied your problem sheet for us to solve it for you. That's not how this site works, friend

Comment: I don't think this is an assignment.

Comment: Assignment or not, the OP's own thoughts and ideas should be included. Simply spitting out questions and posting them is not what the format of this website strives to be.

Comment: The OPs thoughts and ideas are included, up to and including the authoring of a Wolfram Alpha demonstration.

Comment: Scroll down to 17 Aug 04 entry   http://www.mathpuzzle.com/13Sep04.html    See also http://www.mathpuzzle.com/Cube1to69in186x186x186.jpg which shows how I solved it as a series of stacked 2d packing problems.

Comment: I looked in OEIS for $35,37,39,42,45$ and didn't find this sequence.